# How can I see included JavaScript sources?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, greasemonkey

I am trying to script a web page using GreaseMonkey.  (I am using Firebug for help in development.)  The page has a small amount of JavaScript code, but that code pulls in other JS files from the site.  Are the entire collection of JS files stored somewhere on the client side (i.e. on the filesystem somewhere) so that I can view them?  Or better yet, is there a way I can view them in Firebug?  I am a little overwhelmed by Firebug but will be able to follow instructions.

Comment: @jensgram: Good question. I guess someone's in a bad mood today. They also downvoted my (obviously) sensible answer below. Go figure.

Comment: @Robusto Yeah, I upvoted to compensate :)

Comment: It is too bad we don't get to see who downvoted etc.  I upvoted both of you as well.

Comment: Not my down-vote, but I'm guessing it was a RTFM response: http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Comment: @Prestaul: That link is broken.

Comment: @Toddintr: Really? It works for me... That's odd.

Comment: @Prestaul: You're right, for some reason I can't reach the site.  My apologies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click the script tab in Firebug. Then look immediately below the tab for a dropdown that shows all the scripts.

Answer (score -3):

right click - view source

Comment: Fine but the included JS files include yet other files.  I am looking for a way to pull in all files as a collection.

Comment: The source is static, i.e., no dynamically loaded scripts will be shown.

Comment: Is there a way to see dynamically loaded scripts as well?

Comment: Here's the code:

<script src="/tr/js/main.js"></script>

I can paste the source to the root of the site URL and see the source.  I am looking for a more convenient/faster method.  Also, there is no "view source" option on right-click.

Comment: However, since Firefox 3.6 you can click your way through the `<script src>` links.

Comment: @BalusC: I am running 3.6.3 and Firebug 1.5.  In the script tab when I click anywhere on <script src> line nothing happens.